# Не могу разобраться с событием

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Имеются три класса, в первом создал событие и хочу его чтобы при его вызове отсюда же вызывались методы из двух других классов, прочитал пару статей и не могу разобраться как подписаться на созданное событие. Написал в первом скрипте небольшой код который приведу ниже, проверки на null и прочее пока опускаю. Название трех скриптов : ManagerScene,Hook,Score. VSC выдает ошибку ManagerScene.Lose" является тип, но используется как переменная. Я совсем новичок, простите за глупость. Хочу понять сам механизм, смысл использования событий вроде понятен, и логика их действия тоже, но вот с синтаксисом беда. Спасибо заранее.

```
public class ManagerScene : MonoBehaviour
 {
  public delegate void Lose();
  public event Lose StopPlay;

  public void Fail()
    { 
        StopPlay();
    }
  static void example()
    {
        ManagerScene ToManager = new ManagerScene();
        Hook ToHook = new Hook();
        Score ToScore = new Score();
        ToManager.Lose += ToHook.Stop; \\Stop это вызываемый метод из скрипта Hook
        Tomanager.Lose += ToScore.Reset; \\Reset это вызываемый метод из скрипта Score
    }
```

Comment: `ToManager.StopPlay +=`

Comment: `public delegate void Lose();` строчку вообще можно убрать, в .NET уже есть такой делегат "Action" - `public event Action StopPlay;`